# Connecting Winsen ZE11-C2H4 Sensor to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, pins, robotics, wires

How should I connect the [ZE11 Ethylene Sensor](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/products/gas-sensor-module/industrial-application-gas-sensor-module/ze11.html) to an Arduino Uno? I want to know how to attach the pins of the sensor to the Arduino and which resistor I should use. I'm very unprofessional at working with circuits so I most likely will need step-by-step help. To make things easier, I am attaching the [datasheet](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Gas%20Sensor%20Module/Industrial%20Application%20Gas%20Sensor%20Module/ze11-electrochemical-module-manualv1_3.pdf) associated with the sensor. The pin identification and technical parameters are on pages 3-4. Also if someone taught me how to do advanced coding for this project then that would be great. Please note that Winsen is a company based in China, so some things can be inaccurate because of translation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you ask "what resistor to use?" To use for what? What makes you think you want a resistor for anything? Do you know what a resistor does? What it is used for?

Answer (score 0):

Pin 5 & pin 6 are UART Bus. To use UART, connect pin 5 with TX pin on Arduino and pin 6 to RX pin on Arduino. Details about communication settings are at 4th page.
I can't find library for that sensor so guess you're on your own.

UART also Know as [Serial communication](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/).